# hackerrank problem: Given a string, , consisting of alphabets and digits, find the frequency of each digit in the given string

Tags: c, for-loop, char, c-strings, counting

link:https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/frequency-of-digits-1/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

where the wrong here? my codeblocks gives right output but in hackerrank it wrong answer.

````
#include <string.h>`
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char s[1000];
    char a[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int i;
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);
    int l = strlen(s);
    
    for(i=0; i<l; i++){
        int m = s[i]-48;
        a[m]=a[m]+1;
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<9; i++){
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
     printf("%d", a[9]);
     return 0;
}```
````

Comment: It crashes.  Walk through the processing that happens when the input is a letter.  What will `m` be?  What happens when the line of input has  1001 characters ?

Comment: The linked problem statement says **1 ≤ n ≤ 1000** so `char s[1001];`

Answer (score 1):

If you put the condition m>=0 and m<10 then a[m]++. The code will work fine.
Working code. Also updated size to 1001.

```
#include <string.h>`
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char s[1001] ;
    char a[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int i;
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);
    int l = strlen(s);
    
    for(i=0; i<l; i++){
        int m = s[i]-48;
        if(m>=0 && m<10)
        a[m]++;
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<=9; i++){
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char a[10]` ==> `int a[10]` There can be 1000 occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

For starters these  headers

```
#include <string.h>`
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

are redundant. The program can be written without using any declaration from the headers.

Instead you need to include the header `<stdio.h>`

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

The array `a` should have the type `size_t`. Even for the character array having `1000` elements an object of the type `char` can be unable to store such big values.

And the initialization of the array `a` can be simpler

```
size_t a[10] = { 0 };
```

Also as it follows from the assignment the character array `s` should be able to store a string with the length equal to `1000`. It means that the character array itself shall have at least `1001` character to be able to store also the terminating zero character `'\0'` of a string with `1000` characters.

These statements

```
    int m = s[i]-48;
    a[m]=a[m]+1;
```

can result in accessing memory beyond the array `a` that invokes undefined behavior because there is no check whether the current character contains a digit.

The program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[1001];
    size_t digits[10] = { 0 };

    if ( scanf( "%1000[^\n]", s ) == 1 )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++ )
        {
            if ( '0' <= s[i] && s[i] <= '9' )
            {
                ++digits[s[i] - '0'];
            } 
        } 
    
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%c: %zu\n", ( char )( i + '0' ), digits[i] );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For example if to enter string `"122333444455555666666777777788888888999999999"` then the output will look like

```
0: 0
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
5: 5
6: 6
7: 7
8: 8
9: 9
```

If you need to output frequencies in one line then instead of this statement

```
printf( "%c: %zu\n", ( char )( i + '0' ), digits[i] );
```

just write

```
printf( "%zu ", digits[i] );
```

In this case for the above string the output will be

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```